# Test Scores - input validation

Tags: c++

so the program needs to dynamically allocate an array large enough to hold a user=defined number of test scores. once all scores are entered, the array should be passed to a function that sorts them in ascending order. another function should be called that calculates the average score. the program should display the sorted list of scores and averages with appropriate headings. use pointer notation rather than array notation whenever possible.

the problem i am having is making it so that the program doesn't accept negative numbers for test scores.

here is the code.

source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void arrSelectSort(float *, int);
void showArrPtr(float *, int);
void showAverage(float, int);
int main()
{
float *scores,              //To dynamically allocate an array
    total = 0.0,            //Accumulator
    average;                //To hold the averge scores
int numScores;              //To hold the number of test scores
                            //Get the number of test scores.
cout << "How many test scores would you like to process?";
cin >> numScores;
//Dynamically allocate an array large enough to hold that many
//test scores
scores = new float[numScores];
if (scores == NULL)
    return 0;
//Get the test score for each test
cout << "Enter the test scores below.\n";
for (int count = 0; count < numScores; count++)
{
    cout << "Test score #" << (count + 1) << ": ";
    cin >> scores[count];
    while (scores <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Zero or negative numbers not accepted.\n";
        cout << "Test Score #" << (count + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> scores[count];
    }
}
//Calculate the total scores
for (int count = 0; count < numScores; count++)
{
    total += scores[count];
}
//sort the elements of the array pointers
arrSelectSort(scores, numScores);
//Will display them in sorted order.
cout << "The test scores in ascending order are: \n";
showArrPtr(scores, numScores);
showAverage(total, numScores);
//Free memory.
delete[] scores;
return 0;
}
void arrSelectSort(float *array, int size)
{
int startScan, minIndex;
float  minElem;
for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
{
    minIndex = startScan;
    minElem = array[startScan];
    for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
    {
        if (array[index]  < minElem)
        {
            minElem = array[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }
    array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
    array[startScan] = minElem;
    }
}
void showArrPtr(float *array, int size)
{
for (int count = 0; count< size; count++)
    cout << array[count] << " ";
cout << endl;
}
void showAverage(float total, int numScores)
{
float average;
//Calculate the average
average = total / numScores;
//Display the results.
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
cout << "Average Score: " << average << endl;
system("pause");
}
```

modified source.cpp to use double instead of float

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
void arrSelectSort(double *, int);
void showArrPtr(double *, int);
double showAverage(double, int);
int main()
{
double *scores,             //To dynamically allocate an array
    total = 0.0,            //Accumulator
    average;                //To hold the averge scores
int numScores;              //To hold the number of test scores
                            //Get the number of test scores.
cout << "How many test scores would you like to process?";
cin >> numScores;
//Dynamically allocate an array large enough to hold that many
//test scores
scores = new double[numScores];
if (scores == NULL)
    return 0;
//Get the test score for each test
cout << "Enter the test scores below.\n";
for (int count = 0; count < numScores; count++)
{
    cout << "Test score #" << (count + 1) << ": ";
    cin >> scores[count];
    while (scores[count] <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Zero or negative numbers not accepted.\n";
        cout << "Test Score #" << (count + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> scores[count];
    }
}
//Calculate the total scores
for (int count = 0; count < numScores; count++)
{
    total += scores[count];
}
//sort the elements of the array pointers
arrSelectSort(scores, numScores);

cout << "The test scores in ascending order are: \n";
showArrPtr(scores, numScores);
showAverage(total, numScores);

delete[] scores;
return 0;
}
void arrSelectSort(double *array, int size)
{
int startScan, minIndex;
double  minElem;
for (startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
{
    minIndex = startScan;
    minElem = array[startScan];
    for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
    {
        if (array[index]  < minElem)
        {
            minElem = array[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }
    array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
    array[startScan] = minElem;
    }
}
void showArrPtr(double *array, int size)
{
for (int count = 0; count< size; count++)
    cout << array[count] << " ";
cout << endl;
}
double showAverage(double total, int numScores)
{
double average;
//Calculate the average
average = total / numScores;
//Display the results.
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
cout << "Average Score: " << average << endl;
system("pause");
}
```

errors - 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4716   'showAverage': must return a value  ConsoleApplication9 c:\users\kenny\desktop\kenny_fepc1.cpp  85
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C4101   'average': unreferenced local variable  ConsoleApplication9 c:\users\kenny\desktop\kenny_fepc1.cpp  12

please help fix. thank you.

Comment: You probably meant to test for `while (scores[count] <= 0)` in your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking for the value that was input:

```
while (scores <= 0)
```

should be

```
while (scores[count] <= 0)
```

I guess this is homework and you are requested to use c-style arrays. However, please note that using a `std::vector` would make the task very much simpler as it has a dynamic size (that you dont have to handle "manually") and sorting a vector is trivial.

Btw I would suggest you to change the loop to

```
for (int count = 0; count < numScores; count++) {
    scores[count] = -1;
    while (scores[count] <= 0) {
       cout << "Test Score #" << (count + 1) << "(has to be >0) : ";
       cin >> scores[count];
    }
}
```

Duplicate code is always a pain in the ass when you want to make changes to the code. Try to avoid it whenever possible (even if it is only two small lines).

Your other error appears because your `showAverage` is declared to return a `double` but it has no `return`. Either declare it to return nothing:

```
void showAverage(double total, int numScores)
```

or add a `return` statement at the end of the function:

```
return average;
```

Comment: Oops, you have the `while (scores <= 0)` again in your suggestion.

Comment: the code should be modified to use double instead of float. didn't see the extra criteria. here is the updated code. i am getting two errors which i need help with.

Comment: @rimgartargaryen I fixed the mistake pointed out by  πάντα ῥεῖ  and added a fix for the other error

Comment: yea thanks buddy. it was a success. i was able to run the program fine. now the second criteria is to have the user be prompted to enter a name that will sort the numbers for scores according to each name. here is the new code. the full program if you need it ask for it. i will just paste the part of the program that is giving me the error.

Comment: void sortData(int size, char studentName[][6])
    {
 bool swap;
 int temp[6];

 do {
  swap = false;
  for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++) {
   if (strcmp(studentName[count], studentName[count + 1])                       >0) {
    strcpy_s(temp, studentName[count]);
    strcpy_s(studentName[count], studentName[count + 1]);
    strcpy_s(studentName[count + 1], temp);
    swap = true;
   } // end if
  } // end for
 } while (swap);

    }'